# Ravendb Session.Query<T>() method does not return any result when sending Expression<Func<T, bool>> to Where() Extension method

Tags: linq, ravendb

I've got a problem with Ravendb session.Query.Where().
When I use it like this it works perfectly and returns all of UserIdentitiy with User name 'John'  :

```
users = session.Query<UserIdentity>().Where(x => x.UserName == "John").ToList();
```

But when I try to send the Expression as a variable to Where method it fails silently and returns nothing.

```
Expression<Func<UserIdentity, bool>> whereClause = x => x.UserName == "John";

using (var session = _store.OpenSession())
{
    users = session.Query<UserIdentity>().Where(whereClause).ToList();
}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: You can consider creating expression tree using `ExpressionTree` class explicitly and that shall work as expected

Comment: What is the query that is sent to the server? What version are you using?
Note, this _should_ work

Comment: The server version is 4.0.2 and the client is the same. The query is exactly as above in the question body.

Comment: @AyendeRahien I isolated the problem in a separate VS project but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: In this case, please create an issue here: http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com with the repro, we'll look at this.

Comment: @AyendeRahien Thank you. An issue added to the repo : http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RDBC-185

Comment: You didn't add a repro, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
public static class ExpressionTreesExtension
{

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> EqualExpression<T>(string columnName,object value)
    {
        ParameterExpression parameterType = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "object");

        MemberExpression typeColumn = Expression.Property(parameterType, columnName);

        ConstantExpression constant = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(string));

        BinaryExpression binaryExpression = Expression.Equal(typeColumn, constant);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(binaryExpression, parameterType);
    }
}
```

> Code Usage:

```
Expression<Func<UserIdentity, bool>> whereClause = ExpressionTreesExtension.EqualExpression<UserIdentity>("UserName","John");
```

Comment: Why is this better?

Comment: Not better, OP's example shall ideally work but I can guess that Raven DB APIs are not correctly parsing the expression directly provided to the method, just a workaround. Mostly it is the Expression parsing issue.